# How to tell AASM to igonore an event if that event is not applicable for the current state (a transition is not defined)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aasm

I am using AASM. I have an event defined with a transition. It works if the event is raised and the model is in :from state. However it throws InValidTransition exception if the model is in any other state.

```
aasm_state :first
aasm_sate  :second
aasm_state :third

aasm_event :myevent do
  transitions :from => :second, :to => :third
end
```

Now, if I do mymodel.myevent! when mymodel is in :first or :third state, aasm throws InValidTransition. How can I tell aasm to ignore the event when in those states?

Answer (score 3):

```
aasm :column => :state, :whiny_transitions => false do
 state :first
 state  :second
 state :third

 event :myevent do
   transitions :from => :second, :to => :third
 end
end
```

This should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The point of a state machine is that you want to limit which states you can transition to and from.  Why are you using the constraints of a state machine if you want the above functionality?  You could do it the same with

```
def myevent
  self.update_attribute(:state, 'third') if self.state == 'second'
end
```

Or you can do this if you want to continue using state machine

```
aasm_event :myevent do 
    transitions :to => :second, :from => [:second]
    transitions :to => :second, :from => [:first]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only permitted events of your AASM object based on the current state you can do:

`#assuming your aasm object is saved to 'dummy' variable`
`dummy.aasm.events(permitted: true)`

you can also get the name by

`dummy.aasm.events(permitted: true).map(&:name)`